# How to populate a dropdown from database table using MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I want to load data from database table's Column (1 Column only) in a dropdown using MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the List to your model:

```
public List<string> DropDownList= new List<string>();
```

and then in your model create a function to  load the data for the DropDownList from the database:

```
public void GetDropDownList()
{

//Pass your data base connection string here 
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cString))
//Pass your SQL Query and above created SqlConnection object  "c"
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Column1 FROM Table", c))
{
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {

         DropDownList.Add(rdr["Column1"].ToString())

        }
    }
}
}
```

and then in Controller finally, you need to send your model to the view:

```
//Create object of your Model of controller
 Model objModel = new Model();
 //Call function to  load the data for the DropDownList
 objModel.GetDropDownList();
 //return view with your object of model
 return View(objModel);
```

Now in the Razor you can display this:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.DropDownList);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please post your code to have a better solution.Otherwise you could use the foreach loop of the data about the li(html) elements.